# "there exists" or "S exists"

Tags: modifiers, there-is

In the formal writing such as a conference/journal paper, 
which of the following two phrases are correct?

- there exists noun
- Noun exists

In addition, can we use the following phrases to modify the noun from not right after it?

- No mechanism exists that dominates...
- A mechanism exists such that...

If we use "there exists..." the following is possible:

- There exists a mechanism that dominates...

Comment: All of these are fine.

Comment: No differences?

Comment: Not really. "There exists" is not common in normal language, but it's idiomatic in mathematical language.